# What is the significance of the same leading term in a continued fraction expansion?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, continued-fractions

The continued fraction expansion for the golden mean $\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ gives:

`ContinuedFraction[(1 + Sqrt[5])/2, 50]`:
$$ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 $$

and the continued fraction expansion for the silver mean $\lambda = 1 + \sqrt{2}$ gives:

`ContinuedFraction[1 + Sqrt[2], 50]`:
$$ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, \
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, \
2, 2, 2, 2 $$

---

Is there a mathematical reason for the same leading term?  \
Is there a way to predict which numbers will have a continued fraction expansion with the same leading coefficient?

Comment: If the repeated number is $a$ in the continued fraction of $x$, then $x$ satisfies $x=a+1/x$. This equation has solutions $\frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2}$. Maybe you would like to exclude the negative root, because it has absolute value $<1$ and then is going to have a $0$ at the beginning.

Comment: What do you mean with "the same leading term" ? The leading terms are $1$ and $2$, so how do they coincicde ?

Comment: Everyone else seems to have understood my point, sorry for bad phrasing if that’s the case

Comment: @SuperCiocia It looks like you want the leading term to be the same as something else within the sequence, but it isn't clear what.  For instance, do you want all of the terms to be equal?  If so then "same leading term" is a very poor description of this, because that condition does not distinguish the leading term from anything.  The fact that you single out the leading term suggests that you may mean something different, but none of your examples suggest this.

Comment: I meant the $a+\cdots$ terms like in the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see the following
$$x=a+\frac{1}{a+\frac{1}{a+\frac{1}{..}}}$$
$$x=a+\frac{1}{x}$$
$$x^2=ax+1$$
$$x^2-ax-1=0$$
the last equation gives you the continued fraction  with the same leading coefficient

Comment: You left out + signs